# Best practices for replacing a server while not breaking any URLs and not having any downtime?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, ssl-certificate

I tried searching for an answer to this problem but the search term is so broad that nothing helpful popped up.

We have an old server and we want to replace it with a new one (both are physical machines). Both are working, both have their own IP address, subdomain, and SSL cert, and both have the same copy of files that are hosted. I will try to keep my question as straight forward as possible but first I need to say that these are not web servers I'm dealing with, they're streaming media servers and both are running Icecast. The old one is on Windows and the new one is on Linux. (And why we are hosting files on a streaming media server is another question, has to do with public radio regulations.)

It is now time to replace the old one with the new one. **Question is: what is the best way to do that?**

I have identified a two possibilities:

1. Make *newserver.ourdomain.org* the new URL for the streaming server.

   But there are many many URLs out there that would need to be updated. Too many (hundreds) for it to be feasible to get them all, and who knows how many are linked to from other websites.

   So to catch these lost, random, old URLs, we could change the *oldserver.ourdomain.org* A Record to point to the new server's IP instead of the current/old one's IP. This would make the old outdated URLs still valid and accessible from the new server with the new subdomain.

   But to see what happens, I made a test where I made an A Record called *testing.ourdomain.org* and pointed it to the new servers IP. But what happens when you try to open the HTTPS version in a browser is that it throws a really nasty error message saying that this site is security risk. Probably because the certificate's domain is for *newserver.ourdomain.org*. It works fine in http, but not https.

   To fix these problems, we could:

   - Maybe, instead of change the A Record, we could somehow redirect traffic from *oldserver.ourdomain.org* to n*ewserver.ourdomain.org*. I'm not sure that redirection is possible at the DNS level. Is it?? Use a CNAME record?
   - I could make a new A Record, point it to a Apache server and put a redirect in the .htaccess file. Right?
   - Copy the new server's SSL cert to the old server...? If that is even possible then it sounds like a management nightmare because we have to renew the certificate every 3 or 4 months.
2. The second way to do this could be:

   Keep the *oldserver.ourdomain.org* domain but replace the old server's IP with the new server's IP address in the DNS's A Record. Now the same traffic will go to the new, correct server and I don't even have to change any URLs anywhere. Also, if we ever needed to switch to the backup server, this would be easy to do through the DNS.

   However my coworker had a problem with this:

   "the Cert ties the DNS name to an IP address. We would need to get a new Cert for the new server securing oldserver.ourdomain.org and both e new and the old servers would be inactive during the changeover because of potential IP address conflict. This will lead to downtime."

   **Is that even true??**

Seems to me like option #1 is kind of messy. And I'd like to hear your opinions on option #2.

I apologize for nesting multiple questions in here. Please don't feel like you need to answer all of them! I'm just looking for the simplest and best way to do this.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both are working, both have their own IP address, subdomain, and SSL cert, and both have the same copy of files that are hosted.

If both are exactly the same from the outside (serving same content at same URLs, etc.) and you have tested external connectivity to both, you should need only to change the IP addresses of the relevant record, and then wait "some time" (at least the TTL, but preferably longer), before shutting down the old one.

On the contrary, reading:

> But what happens when you try to open the HTTPS version in a browser is that it throws a really nasty error message saying that this site is security risk. Probably because the certificate's domain is for newserver.ourdomain.org. It works fine in http, but not https.

So that means HTTPS is not set up correctly on new server? Obviously you need to fix that first, the new server needs to have a certificate for whatever hosts it has (there is no need to be the same certificate as current/old one).

> I'm not sure that redirection is possible at the DNS level

The concept does not exist. Redirection is an HTTP level mechanism. For your case, DNS just maps names to IP addresses.

> "the Cert ties the DNS name to an IP address.

Not true at all, or at least not for "generic" widely used certificates that encode only an hostname (website name) [summarizing; there can be multiple names in the certificate and/or wildcards; but still only names]. Those certificates have no information on IP addresses.
You can change the IP addres of any HTTPS server and it has no impact on the TLS part and the authentication based on certificate.

The only "vague" thing you can have, if you use a different certificate, is some alerting tool showing a change of certificate. Which can be benign (and happens all the time as certificates are at most 1 year old now, and often just 3 months), or sign of an hijack indeed, but that can not decided just by looking at a certificate change.

Comment: Thank you! And redirecting using .htaccess on an apache server won't work for us because our streaming server uses ports 8000 and 8001.